# UICollectionViewFlowLayout in UICollectionView - Dynamic number of cells in each section

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

So I'm trying to build an EPG like view with UICollectionView. This is my first experience with this framework. Something like [this](https://maniacdev.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/inselectronicprogramguide.gif).

It quickly came to my attention that I would need to implement a custom layout to achieve this EPG. I followed this [guide](http://www.brightec.co.uk/blog/uicollectionview-using-horizontal-and-vertical-scrolling-sticky-rows-and-columns).

I needed to "stick" the first column and row of the collection view and have the EPG scroll both horizontally and vertically. Whilst the tutorial is great I'm having problems adapting it to my specifications. Namely the tutorial declares the columns in each section to be of equal widths. Whereas I require my columns to be dynamic in each section. For e.g.: each row will be a section in itself, so the height of each row will remain constant, but the cells in each row will be of varying width, based on the length of the programme to display in each individual collection view cell.

Can anyone help me out or point me in the right direction on how to achieve this with the below code:

```
- (void)prepareLayout
{
    if ([self.collectionView numberOfSections] == 0) {
        return;
    }

    NSUInteger column = 0; // Current column inside row
    CGFloat xOffset = 0.0;
    CGFloat yOffset = 0.0;
    CGFloat contentWidth = 0.0; // To determine the contentSize
    CGFloat contentHeight = 0.0; // To determine the contentSize

    if (self.itemAttributes.count > 0) { // We don't enter in this if statement the first time, we enter the following times
        for (int section = 0; section < [self.collectionView numberOfSections]; section++) {
            NSUInteger numberOfItems = [self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:section];
            for (NSUInteger index = 0; index < numberOfItems; index++) {
                if (section != 0 && index != 0) { // This is a content cell that shouldn't be sticked
                    continue;
                }
                UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [self layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:index inSection:section]];
                if (section == 0) { // We stick the first row
                    CGRect frame = attributes.frame;
                    frame.origin.y = self.collectionView.contentOffset.y;
                    attributes.frame = frame;

                }
                if (index == 0) { // We stick the first column
                    CGRect frame = attributes.frame;
                    frame.origin.x = self.collectionView.contentOffset.x;
                    attributes.frame = frame;
                }
            }
        }

        return;
    }

    // The following code is only executed the first time we prepare the layout
    self.itemAttributes = [@[] mutableCopy];
    self.itemsSize = [@[] mutableCopy];

    // Tip: If we don't know the number of columns we can call the following method and use the NSUInteger object instead of the NUMBEROFCOLUMNS macro
    // NSUInteger numberOfItems = [self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:section];

    // We calculate the item size of each column
    if (self.itemsSize.count != NUMBEROFCOLUMNS) {
        [self calculateItemsSize];
    }

    // We loop through all items
    for (int section = 0; section < [self.collectionView numberOfSections]; section++) {
        NSMutableArray *sectionAttributes = [@[] mutableCopy];

        for (NSUInteger index = 0; index < NUMBEROFCOLUMNS; index++) {
            CGSize itemSize = [self.itemsSize[index] CGSizeValue];

            // We create the UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes object for each item and add it to our array.
            // We will use this later in layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:index inSection:section];
            UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributesForCellWithIndexPath:indexPath];
            attributes.frame = CGRectIntegral(CGRectMake(xOffset, yOffset, itemSize.width, itemSize.height));

            if (section == 0 && index == 0) {
                attributes.zIndex = 1024; // Set this value for the first item (Sec0Row0) in order to make it visible over first column and first row
            } else if (section == 0 || index == 0) {
                attributes.zIndex = 1023; // Set this value for the first row or section in order to set visible over the rest of the items
            }
            if (section == 0) {
                CGRect frame = attributes.frame;
                frame.origin.y = self.collectionView.contentOffset.y;
                attributes.frame = frame; // Stick to the top
            }
            if (index == 0) {
                CGRect frame = attributes.frame;
                frame.origin.x = self.collectionView.contentOffset.x;
                attributes.frame = frame; // Stick to the left
            }

            [sectionAttributes addObject:attributes];

            xOffset = xOffset+itemSize.width;
            column++;

            // Create a new row if this was the last column
            if (column == NUMBEROFCOLUMNS) {
                if (xOffset > contentWidth) {
                    contentWidth = xOffset;
                }

                // Reset values
                column = 0;
                xOffset = 0;
                yOffset += itemSize.height;
            }
        }
        [self.itemAttributes addObject:sectionAttributes];
    }

    // Get the last item to calculate the total height of the content
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [[self.itemAttributes lastObject] lastObject];
    contentHeight = attributes.frame.origin.y+attributes.frame.size.height;
    self.contentSize = CGSizeMake(contentWidth, contentHeight);
}

- (CGSize)collectionViewContentSize
{
    return self.contentSize;
}

- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return self.itemAttributes[indexPath.section][indexPath.row];
}


- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSMutableArray *attributes = [@[] mutableCopy];

    for (NSArray *section in self.itemAttributes) {

        [attributes addObjectsFromArray:[section filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
            return CGRectIntersectsRect(rect, [evaluatedObject frame]);
        }]]];
    }

    return attributes;
}

- (BOOL)shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:(CGRect)newBounds
{
    return YES; // Set this to YES to call prepareLayout on every scroll
}


- (CGSize)sizeForItemWithColumnIndex:(NSUInteger)columnIndex
{
    NSLog(@"sizeForItemWithColumnIndex");
    NSString *text;
    for (NSUInteger index = 0; index < NUMBEROFCOLUMNS; index++) {


        text = @"asdf";

    }


    CGSize size = [text sizeWithAttributes: @{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:15]}];
    NSLog(@"Size of %@", NSStringFromCGSize(size));
    if (columnIndex == 0) {
        size.width += 1; // In our design the first column should be the widest one
    }
    return CGSizeMake([@(size.width + 50) floatValue], 40); // Extra space of 9px for all the items
}



- (void)calculateItemsSize
{
    NSLog(@"calculate item size");

    for (NSUInteger index = 0; index < NUMBEROFCOLUMNS; index++) {

        if (self.itemsSize.count <= index) {

            CGSize itemSize = [self sizeForItemWithColumnIndex:index];

            NSValue *itemSizeValue = [NSValue valueWithCGSize:itemSize];

            [self.itemsSize addObject:itemSizeValue];
        }
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok so answered this myself, by starting from scratch. Before preparing the layout I loaded the xml web service for the programme and channel info into a SQLite database. Pulled the rows using third party library FMDB and calculated the frame (xPos, yPos, cellWidth, cellHeight) of each cell based on the number of minutes each programme runs for. (Except for the first section which contains the timeline, and the first item in each section which contains the icon for each particular channel.) Each calculation I saved to a dictionary to reference for the layout.

```
- (void)calculateFramesForAllPrograms {

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0];
    NSInteger counterForDatabaseRow = 0;

    for (NSInteger section = 0; section < numOfChannels + EXTRA_ROW_FOR_TIME; section++) {

        if(section==0){

            for (NSInteger items = 0; items <=HOURS_IN_A_DAY + EXTRA_ROW_FOR_TIME; items++){

                if(items==0){

                    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(xPos, yPos, TILE_HEIGHT, TILE_HEIGHT);
                    NSString *rectString = NSStringFromCGRect(frame);
                    indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:items inSection:section];
                    //NSLog(@"INDEX PATH %@", indexPath);
                    self.frameInfo[indexPath] = rectString;

                    xPos = xPos+TILE_HEIGHT;

                }else {

                    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(xPos, yPos, self.timeTile.width, self.timeTile.height);
                    NSString *rectString = NSStringFromCGRect(frame);
                    indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:items inSection:section];
                    //NSLog(@"INDEX PATH %@", indexPath);
                    self.frameInfo[indexPath] = rectString;

                    xPos = xPos+self.timeTile.width;

                }
            }

        } else {

            xPos = 0;
            //NSLog(@"SECTION COUNT: %lu", section);
            NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT COUNT(channel_code) AS channels FROM epg WHERE channel_code='%@", self.channelCodes[section-EXTRA_ROW_FOR_TIME]];
            NSString *completedQuery = [query stringByAppendingString:@"'"];
            //NSLog(@"string %@", completedQuery);
            db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:[Utility getDatabasePath]];
            [db open];
            NSUInteger itemCount = [db intForQuery:completedQuery];

                for (NSInteger item = 0; item <itemCount+EXTRA_ROW_FOR_TIME; item++) {

                    //NSLog(@"Item: %lu Item: %lu", item, itemCount);

                    if(item==0){

                        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(xPos, yPos, TILE_HEIGHT, TILE_HEIGHT);
                        NSString *rectString = NSStringFromCGRect(frame);
                        indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:item inSection:section];
                        //NSLog(@"INDEX PATH %@", indexPath);
                        self.frameInfo[indexPath] = rectString;

                        xPos = xPos+TILE_HEIGHT;

                    }else {

                        if (item==itemCount){
                            //NSLog(@"LAST ITEM %@", self.endTimes[counter]);
                            isLastItem = TRUE;
                        }

                        CGSize tileSize = [self sizeForProgramTile:counterForDatabaseRow];
                        //NSLog(@"TILE SIZE RETURNED %@", NSStringFromCGSize(tileSize));
                        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(xPos, yPos, tileSize.width, tileSize.height);
                        NSString *rectString = NSStringFromCGRect(frame);
                        indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:item inSection:section];
                        //NSLog(@"INDEX PATH %@", indexPath);
                        self.frameInfo[indexPath] = rectString;

                        xPos = xPos+tileSize.width;

                        counterForDatabaseRow++;

                    }

                }
        }

        yPos += TILE_HEIGHT;
    }
    //NSLog(@"FRAME INFO %@", self.frameInfo);
}
```

Comment: Did you able to achieve same thing. I am also looking for same code to make the cell width dynamic as per the channel program duration.